# Python-array about gcd

Tags: python, arrays, greatest-common-divisor

[Q](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQVNS.jpg)
I tried many ways but it didn't work. please show me a way.

My last code that I tried;

```
n = int(sys.argv[1])

x = stdarray.create2D(n,n,0)


for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        if i > j:
            while j != 0:
                z = i % j
                i = j
                j = z
        elif j > i:
            while i != 0:
                z = j % i
                j = i
                i = z
        if i == 1 or j == 1:
            stdio.write("* ")
        else:
            stdio.write(" ")
    stdio.writeln()
```

And I explain some details from my codes, I use different library than normal.
stdio.writeln is like print. you should think it is print...

and stdarray.create bla bla is a array.
first n is represent: row
second n is represent: column
so it will be square matrix as you can see. (because both of them are "n")

and my code's output is; if i entered 5 in argv. it will be 5x5 matrix. and output is;

```
0 1 2 3 4 
1 1 1 3 4
2 1 1 3 4
3 1 1 3 4
4 1 1 3 4
```

But it's wrong. for example a[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NhGtg.jpg) = 3 in this output.
but it's wrong. it must be; 1.
gcd of 3 and 2 should be 1. not 3.

I tried many ways. but I didn't solve this question.

---

For Primusa,
Your code is correct but in my university, we haven't see yet functions.
su I can't use functions.

so this is correct code that yours,

```
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        GCD = gcd(i, j)
        if GCD == 1:
            stdio.write("* ")
        else:
            stdio.write(" ")
    stdio.writeln()
```

and I tried to change that code without function. but doesn't work.
my code,

```
for x in range(n):
    for y in range(n):
        while y != 0:
            temp = y
            y = x % y
            x = temp
        GCD = x
        if GCD == 1:
            stdio.write("* ")
        else:
            stdio.write(" ")
    stdio.writeln()
```

your output,
[Your code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HHx97.jpg)
my output,
[my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NhGtg.jpg)
but my code is wrong. how my code's output will be like yours?

normally my euclid's method workes right. but when I use that code in for nesting it won't work.

Comment: The output from your program is nothing like what you say it is. For one thing, there's nothing called `stdio` in Python, or `stdarray`. These obviously come from some third-party lib you haven't mentioned. But if you replace `stdio` with `sys.stdout` and just remove the `stdarray` because it isn't being used anywhere, you only print out asterisks, not numbers. And not lined up as an matrix, because you only print one space instead of two for a miss. You need a [mcve] that includes code that actually produces the claimed output and could conceivably produce the desired output with a bug fix.

Comment: Also, it's not clear which of the `i, j, z` values you're expecting the GCD to be in, but none of them are `3` at the end of a loop for `3, 2` or for `2, 3`—either way, one of the variables is `1` and the others are `0`. So, the bug you're asking us to fix isn't in the code you've shown us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your biggest problem seems to be your implementation of gcd.
An easy way to get gcd in python is to just import it:

```
from fractions import gcd
```

If you want to implement it yourself, you can use Euclid's method:

```
def gcd(a, b):
    while b:
        a, b = b, a%b
    return a
```

To put this in the context of your code:

```
n = int(sys.argv[1])

for row in range(n):
    for col in range(n):
        GCD = gcd(row, col)
        if GCD == 1:
            stdio.write("* ")
        else:
            stdio.write(" ")
stdio.writeln()
```

If you want to do it without any functions, remember to use separate variables, because the function may unintentionally modify those values:

```
for x in range(n):
    for y in range(n):
        a = y
        b = x
        while b:
            a, b = b,a%b
        GCD = a
        if GCD == 1:
            stdio.write("* ")
        else:
            stdio.write("  ") #note outputs weren't lining up so I added an extra whitespace
    stdio.writeln()
```

Comment: I already use Euclid's method. But it's not problem. problem is different. I wrote above.

Comment: No. The problem is that your implementation of gcd is not correct.

Comment: @Primusa No, the problem is that what he's shown us isn't remotely like his actual code, so it's impossible to guess what's really wrong with it. What he's posted does calculate GCDs correctly (at least in the cases he mentioned), and doesn't give the results he claims, which makes it impossible to debug. Despite your valiant effort at reading his mind, you can't figure out what code he's really asking about if he won't show it to us.

Comment: Thank you both of you. but Primusa is right. I tried that code and it worked. thank you so much both of you.

Comment: Primusa your code is right. but I can't use function. I would do this program without function. please read my write above. ı edited.

Comment: you are awesome and lifesaver. each point that you mentioned are very imported and understandable to me. thank you so much.

Comment: Happy to help :)